# MongoError $regex has to be a string

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js, mongodb

The problem is, I'm getting an error in my Console:

```
{ [MongoError: $regex has to be a string]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: '$regex has to be a string',
  waitedMS: 0,
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: '$regex has to be a string',
  code: 2 }
```

Basically I'm using Ajax to get data from my MongoDB, where I'm searching for a user. Without Ajax, my search function is working correctly, but I want to search for a user without the need of refreshing the web-page and just fill up my HTML. Here is all my code:

**Server code:**

```
app.post("/searchresult", function(req, res){
    var thename = req.body.thename;
    LoginUser.find({
        $or: [

            {"firstname": {$regex: thename, $options: 'i'}},
            {"lastname": {$regex: thename, $options: 'i'}}
        ]
    }, function(err, searchedUser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            res.render("searchprofile", {foundUser: searchedUser});
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<form class="form-inline" id="searchform" action="/searchresult" method="POST">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search people" name="thename" id="searchinput">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
$("#searchform").on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var searchInp = $("#searchinput");

  $.ajax({
    url: '/searchresult',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ firstname: searchInp.val() }),
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      searchInp.val('');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(thename)` show?

Comment: with ajax: thename is undefined. without ajax: thename has a value

Comment: `undefined` isn't a string, so that's your problem

Comment: any idea why it is returning undefined? is my ajax wrong? thanks!

Comment: Well, you're posting `firstname` instead of `thename` in your ajax, so...

Comment: i tried changing from firstname to thename, but still didnt work, i still receive the error on my git bash.

Comment: check by `console.log(req.body)` in server side what you sent from client side

Comment: it's just an empty array { }

Answer (score 2):

// thename = `${thename}`

LoginUser.find({
$or: [

```
    {"firstname": {$regex: `${thename}`, $options: 'i'}},
    {"lastname": {$regex: `${thename}`, $options: 'i'}}
]
```

},

Answer (score 0):

check your data maybe < thename > is something else than string.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be an issue with the actual type inside mongoDB. I had this error when I was trying to query on a boolean,
so my schema was

```
      const schema = {
         email:string,
         active: boolean,
         role:string
      }
```

but I was trying to query on all of these, with $or.

```
     if (typeof query === 'string') {
          queryObject['$or'] = [
            { email: { $regex: `${query}`, $options: 'i' } },
            { role: { $regex: `${query}`, $options: 'i' } },
            { active: { $regex: `${query}`, $options: 'i' } },
          ]
        }
```

So the issue was with the **active** it's a boolean, however I was trying to query it with a regex and this cause the issue.

Summary:

- Check your schema types if you're using mongoose, or your data type inside mongodb.
- Query also should be a string for sure.